# Is this dependent or independent sentence?

Tags: sentence, clauses, sentence-patterns

**"Making trial of everything, with trust in new joy, and stirring the human kindness in all eyes that looked on her."**

If it is an independent clause, could you please tell which is the subject and which is the verb.

Comment: The subject is "she".

Comment: @GregLee where is the verb?

Comment: I won't answer that, since your question sounds like homework you've been assigned.  I was just giving a hint.

Comment: It's _not_ a sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought so. However, the sentence was in the literature passage. It was written as an independent clause, beginning after semicolon and ending with a dot.

Comment: @RamPillai Then why it is written as a dependent clause in the following: "Eppie was a creature of endless claims and ever-growing desires, seeking and loving sunshine, and living sounds, and living movements; making trial of everything, with trust in new joy, and stirring the human kindness in all eyes that looked on her."

Comment: "I came, I saw, I conquered" is accepted by (almost) all and has three independent clauses separated by _commas_.  The venerated author HG Wells, in 'The Time Machine', writes "... [T]he jerking sun became a streak of fire, a brilliant arch, in space; the moon a fainter fluctuating band; and I could see nothing of the stars, save now and then a brighter circle flickering in the blue."  (I've omitted the first half of the sentence!) 'Rules' taught by institutions teaching below degree level are often rules of thumb, approximations, guidelines. ELU tries to aim at more advanced analyses.

Comment: What are those advanced analyses? Could you give me a specific example? @EdwinAshworth

Comment: @Meraki: //Eppie was a creature of endless claims and ever-growing desires, seeking and loving sunshine, and living sounds, and living movements; making trial of everything, with trust in new joy, and stirring the human kindness in all eyes that looked on her."// This is correct, because it has got a verb/ tense, unlike the given example. Here, Eppie was a creature... is independent clause; and the remaining are participial phrases.

Comment: @Edwin: //I came, I saw, I conquered// You are right here. These are three independent clauses. Even when written as "I came, saw and conquered." it implies "I came, I saw, I conquered." making it three independent clauses

Comment: @RamPillai I thought the semicolon ended the independent sentence. So, the sentence after the semicolon should be independent right? Or are there other grammar rules that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Meraki: Even with semicolon, there can be independent clause. When I say, for example, "I understood what the students were asking....", here, "I understood..." can stand alone; but "what the students were asking" is incomplete; and cannot stand alone; hence dependent on the former clause.

Comment: @RamPillai I'm wondering if the sentence "making trial of everything... that looked on her." could stand alone as a dependent clause.

Comment: With @Edwin's permission, to reply to Meraki: I came, I saw, I conquered; though separated by commas, each is a clause having a subject and verb. The jerking sun became a streak of fire – independent clause. Also means, ….it became a brilliant arch in space; independent clause.  The moon (is) a fainter….; independent clause;  I could see nothing of the stars save now and then (except now and then); independent clause   (I could then see) a brighter circle flickering in the blue….; independent clause. Each can remain alone; not dependent on other clause(s).

Comment: @RamPillai yes. I can see the independent clauses you are referencing. But, is the one I'm asking is independent or not?

Comment: @Meraki: Making trial of everything - participial phrase. 2) All eyes that looked on her.... This cannot stand alone. "All eyes" is a noun phrase and "that looked on her" is a dependent clause. Here, I should apologize, is a clause, but not independent. It is an adjective clause to the noun 'All eyes'.

Comment: @RamPillai yes, thank you. I thought it was a dependent clause. But, why it is written as an independent clause in the context? Is it simply because of stylistic reasons? Could you write any way you want?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a sentence, only 3 adjuncts (adverbs) conjoined together. It can be understood, though, that the subject of the potential clause would be "she."

Answer (score 0):

It's three dependent clauses in search of a main clause.